# Hilbert Matrix in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix

A Hilbert matrix is a square matrix whose elements are given by:

```
 A[i][j]= 1 / (i+j+1)
```

My code is:

```
def Hilbert(n):
    H = [[0]*n]*n
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            H[i][j] = 1/(i+j+1)
    return H
```

e.g. for n = 3 it should return

```
[1, 1/2, 1/3]  
[1/2, 1/3, 1/4]  
[1/3, 1/4, 1/5]
```

but it returns 3 rows of

```
[1/3, 1/4, 1/5]
```

where's my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do

```
H = [[0]*n]*n
```

the last `*n` makes shallow copies of the first `[0 0 0 .... (n)]` list. By modifying any of the elements in the first column, you change all the columns (the items inside the lists are references to the first).

[Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) is good for array manipulation, but if you don't want to use it try

```
H = [[0]*n for i in xrange(n)]
```

To see if you have elements that point to the same integer, you can try

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        print(id(H[i][j])) # [id() is the memory address](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id)
```

Aside: Using numpy it's

```
H = np.zeros((n, n))
```

ref : https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is in the H init part:

H = [[0]*n]*n

This create list of references to the same, inner, list.
Thus all rows return the same value.

Try with:

H = [[0]*n for i in range(n)]